# Angular rest call. Handle fetched array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I am fetching array via angular's factory and I am able to display the correctly on page. I am however unable to get any object from that array and get 'undefined'.

How I can get to objects in this array?

Pieces of the code below:

In controller:

```
 self.readings = Reading.query({
                media: media,
                id: residence.id
            });
            //shows the array
            console.log(self.readings);
            //undefined
            console.log(self.readings[0])
```

The result of thise console logs:
[image]

And the factory itself:

```
 return $resource(
    path + "/api/v1/readings.json?media=:media&residence_id=:id", {
        id: "@id",
        media: "@media"
    }, 
    {
        query: {
            method: "GET",
            isArray: true
        },
        update: {
            method: "PUT"
        }
    }
);
```

On the html page I have this which works just fine:

```
<tr ng-repeat="r in ctrl.readings">
```

**EDIT**

As per advice I have changed the code to

```
Reading.query({ media: media, id: residence.id }).then(function(response){ self.readings = response },function(error) { console.log(error); });
```

Unfortunately in web's console I get:

> Error: Reading.query(...).then is not a function

Comment: Reading.query will return a promise , so you have to resolve it like this : 
`Reading.query({
   media: media,
   id: residence.id
 }).then(function(response){

  self.readings = response
},function(error)
{
console.log(error);
})`

Answer (score 2):

need to catch the response inside a promise

```
 Reading.query({
   media: media,
   id: residence.id
 }).then(function(response){

  self.readings = response
})
```

Comment: Then I get:
Error: Reading.query(...).then is not a function